# pandas silently dropping useful rows while mergin

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to merge two data frames based on an inner join when I am joining those data frames they are dropping the rows which are useful.`

```
    import pandas as pd
    import zipfile

    read_advertiser_mapping = pd.read_csv("advertiserMarketMapping.csv",
                                          encoding="utf-8")
   print(read_advertiser_mapping.shape)
   (37, 2)

    read_dmc_static_zf = zipfile.ZipFile("DMC_Static_Conversions.zip")
    read_dmc_static = pd.read_csv(read_dmc_static_zf.open(zipfile.ZipFile.namelist(read_dmc_static_zf)[0]),
                                  skiprows=9, skipfooter=1, engine='python', encoding="utf-8")
    print(read_dmc_static.shape)
    (114421, 8)

    merge_df = pd.merge(read_dmc_static, read_advertiser_mapping, 
    on='Advertiser')
   print(merge_df.shape)
   110944

    writer_file = pd.ExcelWriter("file.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter", datetime_format="YYYY-MM-DD")

    x = merge_df.to_excel(writer_file)
    writer_file.save()
    writer_file.close()
```

File **Advertiser Marketing** has 37 rows and  **DMC_Static_Conversions**
114421 rows and after merging this should return 114303 rows however only 
returning 110944.

Could you please help also let me know where can I place the data?

Comment: Hello, Monika. The inner merge, pandas default behaviour, only keep rows where the merge “on” value exists in both the left and right dataframes. How do you know that the correct number of rows supposed to be 114303?

Comment: @FabianoBattaglin I produced manual file by applying manual merge so that it returns the 114303 rows. I don't know why it keeps skipping the rows when applying to merge through.

Comment: @FabianoBattaglin I also know which rows are dropping though can't able to figure out why its happening while applying a merge

Comment: Since you know which rows are being dropped, I suggest you to take a closer look to see if there is any patterns between them (NA's, original df, etc). Then you can change merge parameters according to your finding (Have you tried playing with them?) 
Another idea is doing the opposite analysis: to assist with the identification of where rows originate from, Pandas provides an “indicator” parameter that can be used with the merge function which creates an additional column called “_merge” in the output that labels the original source for each row.

Comment: @FabianoBattaglin did all my analysis and used a different column for on= parameter which works fine now.